# Leaflet Search Address By Name

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, geocoding, offline

How to search address by name in leaflet?
I use leaflet search control but just search marker in map. the example in [https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/google-geocoding.html](http://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/google-geocoding.html) use geocoding, can i search address without use google geocoding api or nominatim ? cause my project is offline.

Answer (score 1):

If your project is offline then you need to install a local geocoder, for example Nominatim.